# How to send Ajax request to a Component function with Symfony?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony-1.4

I have a Button with some `data-attributes` and a Component **MyComp**.

When the Component is called, a function should be run before : `executeMyComp(sfWebRequest $request)`. Into my **executeMyComp** I do some Propel SQL but i need some a Variable send from the Button through AJAX.

1. should the Ajax save the Variable into the Symfony Session? if yes how?
2. Or should i send through Ajax a sfWebRequest if yes how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for function before `executeMyComp` you can use `preExecute` functions. they run before actual actions and you can write your code by checking if it's an specific action by using getModuleName and getActionName methods.

and about your second question, i always use JQuery Ajax functions because by using prototype ajax there is always some conflicts. it's so simple to use and you can send values with the request to an specific action. so there is no need to add them to session

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your action URL",
            data: fields, // this fields variable(a string full of parameters) will be sent by request and you can get them using getParameter
            success: function(data){
                //if everything goes well you come here.here you can show your response.
            }
        });
});
```

of course there is no need to say that you can save your attributes via jquery to a variable before send them via ajax by something like this:

```
var myvar=$("#componentid").val();
```